# Difference of ALIGN() and round_up() macro in the Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, memory-alignment

I'm recently exploring alignment mechanisms inside the Linux kernel, however, I'm confused by two macros, which are `ALIGN()` and `round_up()`, they have different implementation but same purpose (as my understanding), which is do the 2^n-bytes round up.

I'm curious about the reason they need two macros with different impl but same output.

Also, they are both inside the same header file, `include/linux/kernel.h`.

[Impl of `round_up()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L71):

```c
#define __round_mask(x, y) ((__typeof__(x))((y)-1))

#define round_up(x, y) ((((x)-1) | __round_mask(x, y))+1)
```

[Impl of ALIGN()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L33):

```c
#define __ALIGN_KERNEL(x, a)        __ALIGN_KERNEL_MASK(x, (typeof(x))(a) - 1)
#define __ALIGN_KERNEL_MASK(x, mask)    (((x) + (mask)) & ~(mask))

#define ALIGN(x, a)     __ALIGN_KERNEL((x), (a))
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the reply. Can you be more specific? AFAIK and even tested (since I was doubt my understanding), `round_up` and `ALIGN` are both returning next divisible on `a`, `y`.

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted description of `round_up` incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not anymore in the same header. `__ALIGN_KERNEL*()` now is a part of UAPI. But the main differences I guess are:

**a)** slightly different implementation and

**b)** the historical reason, i.e. the author of *[9b3be9f99203](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9b3be9f99203) ("Move round_up/down to kernel.h")* simple hadn't found the counterpart to `ALIGN()` which appears in the generic headers later, in *[ed067d4a859f](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ed067d4a859f) ("linux/kernel.h: Add ALIGN_DOWN macro")*.

I would recommend to drop an email to LKML with authors of above mentioned commits, Kees Cook, perhaps some other people to ask them to take a look.

Comment: Got it, I will try to reach them. Thanks for the explanation!